# Pass props to the component you came from when user clicks back button on window, in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes, url-routing, react-props

I am going from component A to component B via routing and I need to pass prop to A when user clicks on the windows back button while on component B. Is there any way of doing this? I am using React's history.push to navigate between components.

Comment: There are multiple ways to do this, Can you show us what you have tried? Thanks.

Comment: Well I have a back button (a react button) on my component B and there I am using histroy.push to go back to A and there I am passing my props to A in history.state. Now I just need to figure out how to do this when the user presses the windows back button.

Comment: There are still multiple ways to do this. The easiest would be to put the state in a container the is of a higher order then both of your routes. You can use a state provider with the context api, manually pass state between pages, serialize state into local storage, there are so many different options available. Seeing some code would help decide which is the best for you.

Comment: I can't use local storage. Can you explain the state provider approach please?

Comment: You can read about it [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a service (it's a singleton) to share state together.

See my example project [at here](https://codesandbox.io/s/k9pln9465)